# Java - Read mixed data types from a file (char + int + binary)

Tags: java, android, file, io

I am reading data from a file (Actually a fifo pipe).

The format is as follows

```
SECTION_NAME
SECTION_SIZE
SECTION_DATA[SECTION_SIZE]
.....
```

**Ex:**

```
pps_frame
1404
<Binary data of 1404 bytes>
sps_frame
1000
<Binary data of 1000 bytes>
...
```

How do i Read the binary data of 1404 bytes in the above example. Note that the `SECTION_SIZE` keeps varying.

PS: In my native code, I am writing this data into the pipe.

Comment: Read first two lines of data. Parse second line to an int X, then read the next X bytes of the file?

Comment: Are there no separators between these elements? Is there any criteria of last element starting character?

Comment: `byte[] data = new byte[size]; in.readFully(data);` to complete the james bond cricket.

Comment: @cricket_007 How do i do that? I am a c programmer and I am new to Java. It is looking complicated to just parse the file. i tried reading FileInputStream but that is giving me byte[]. I need to convert it to int? Basically I am looking for a method to do what you exactly asked me to do..

Comment: @Stallion Like i said in the question, I am writing the data into the file.. So, I can put any seperators.. For now I have put "\n" and tried to read line by line using Bufferredreader.. But the SECTION_DATA does not seem to coming as a whole using readLine()

Comment: @JoopEggen What is the value of size? There are continuous patterns in a file with the format i mentioned..

Comment: @mk after your latest remark, coming from C, and this indeed is a bit circumstantial in Java, turned all into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is indeed a bit circumstantial: first reading text, and then binary data. Here a solution, staying with binary reading.

```
FileInputStream fin = ...
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin, 2048);
String name = readLine(bin);
String lineWithSize = readLine(bin);
int size = Integer.parseInt(lineWithSize);
byte[] data = new byte[size];
bin.read(data, 0, size);
bin.close();
```

With a help function `readLine` for reading bytes, and converting them to text.
As BufferedReader.readLine it discards the line endings, here following the simplified assumption that a line ending is either LF or CR+LF.

```
String readLine(BufferedInputStream bin) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (;;) {
        int ch = bin.read();
        if (ch == -1) {
            break;
        }
        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') {
            if (ch == '\r') {
                bin.read();
            }
            break;
        }
        baos.write(ch);
    }
    return baos.toString("ISO-8859-1"); // Basic Latin-1 encoding.
}
```

Reading text with a Reader does always a conversion of bytes using some encoding of those bytes. To its internal Unicode (a char is two bytes UTF-16). Hence you cannot 100% perfectly read bytes into a String. Because of size and conversion it is not even desirable.

Comment: What a relief! Thank you. I am now trying it out.. BDW in new BufferedInputStream(fin, 2048); 2048 is the maximum size of the total section.. isn't it?

Comment: 2048 is a buffer size. It would be nice if the section was read with that and not much more, but especially I did not want my for-loop single byte reads let stand there without having a buffer mentioned. And a power of 2 as we programmers are superstitious.